# App Engine - background threads not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is there any reason why background threads spawned by `ExecutorService` with fixed thread pool don't work?

```
ThreadFactory bgThreadFactory = ThreadManager.backgroundThreadFactory();
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads, bgThreadFactory);
```

If I create `MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()` it works like a charm however without multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that backround threads works also with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads, bgThreadFactory);` However, for some reason, logs are not produced by background threads (at least not all the time - still don't know why).

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java) on app engine java, you need to create a thread factory by calling `com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory()` and then you call the factory's `newRequestThread()` method.

Comment: thanks for the reply. `currentRequestThreadFactory()` creates threads that are scoped to current request. These threads will be interrupted at the end of the current request and must complete within the request deadline. I need to use `backgroundThreadFactory()` which create threads that are able to "outlive" current request i.e. continues on backgroud after request is complete.

Comment: as per the doc background threads are only available for backends https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager.html#createBackgroundThread-java.lang.Runnable-